# How many distant points can be located in four-dimensional cube?

Tags: computational-geometry

Let $n$ distinct points in the four-dimensional cube 
$$\{ (x,y,z,t):0\le x, x\le 1,0\le y, y\le 1,0\le z, z\le 1,0\le t, t \le 1 \} $$ be such that
all the distances between these points are (strictly) greater than one. How much can $n$ be?
I know the answer in three dimensions is 7. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulxj393izuzughy/7%20points%20in%20cube.nb?dl=0) and  [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjlij6iiquzp4h9/7%20points%20in%20cube.pdf?dl=0) is my Mathematica code which finds 7 points in the 3D cube, producing

> {1., {Indexed[x, {1}] -> 1., Indexed[x, {2}] -> 0.736543, 
>     Indexed[x, {3}] -> 0.000953636, Indexed[x, {4}] -> 0.999888, 
>     Indexed[x, {5}] -> 0.0010957, Indexed[x, {6}] -> 0., 
>     Indexed[x, {7}] -> 1., Indexed[y, {1}] -> 0.967476, 
>     Indexed[y, {2}] -> 0.00179236, Indexed[y, {3}] -> 0.712727, 
>     Indexed[y, {4}] -> 7.67595*10^-8, Indexed[y, {5}] -> 0.000973333, 
>     Indexed[y, {6}] -> 0.974891, Indexed[y, {7}] -> 1., 
>     Indexed[z, {1}] -> 0.0000193274, Indexed[z, {2}] -> 0.00039306, 
>     Indexed[z, {3}] -> 2.28036*10^-7, Indexed[z, {4}] -> 0.965628, 
>     Indexed[z, {5}] -> 0.703141, Indexed[z, {6}] -> 0.980439, 
>     Indexed[z, {7}] -> 0.99999}}

```
 ListPointPlot3D[Table[{Indexed[x, j], Indexed[y, j], Indexed[z, j]}, {j, 1, 
7}] /. %[[2]]]
```

[image]

Eight points cannot be located in such a way (see [this article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C26EE16A299209D61DE00D8A621AA3B5/S0008439500052826a.pdf/on_the_densest_packing_of_spheres_in_a_cube.pdf)).
What is such $n$ in four dimensions?